# webdriverIO and iOS simulator browser testing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am attempting to run browser testing through the iOS simulator using webdriverIO. But instead of running the browser through the iOS simulator, it is just running it through the desktop version of Safari. I am not getting any errors. I am using the wdio test runner and this is in my config. Any suggestions?

```
capabilities: [
    {
        appiumVersion: '1.7.1',
        deviceName: 'iPhone Simulator',
        deviceOrientation: 'portrait',
        platformversion: '9.0',
        platformName: 'iOS',
        port: '4723',
        browserName: 'safari'                        
    }
],
```

/

```
services: ['selenium-standalone', 'appium'],
appium: {
    args: {
        address: '127.0.0.1',
        commandTimeout: '7200',
        sessionOverride: true,
        debugLogSpacing: true,
        platformVersion: '9.0',
        platformName: 'iOS',
        showIosLog: true,
        deviceName: 'iPhone',
        nativeInstrumentsLib: true,
        isolateSimDevice: true,
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work. I had set my config like so:

```
capabilities: [
{
        maxInstances: 1,
        browserName: 'safari',
        appiumVersion: '1.7.1',
        automationName: 'Appium',
        deviceName: 'iPhone 7 Plus',
        deviceOrientation: 'portrait',
        platformVersion: '11.0',
        platformName: 'iOS'
}
```

-

```
services: ['selenium-standalone', 'appium'],
appium: {
    args: {
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    commandTimeout: '7200',
    sessionOverride: true,
    debugLogSpacing: true,
    showIosLog: true,
    nativeInstrumentsLib: true,
    isolateSimDevice: true,
    }
},

port: 4723,
```